# ASP .Net Hidden field setting but not posting in IE

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

In my web form I have an ASP Hidden field as such:
`<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" OnValueChanged="HiddenField1_ValueChanged" />` I am current setting the value of this field client side as such

```
document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenField1").value = type + pngUrl;
```

Then I call 
`document.forms[0].submit();` to post the page.
The changed value of the hidden field successfully posts in both chrome and firefox, but in IE the DOM Viewer says the data is inside the hidden field but on inspection of the post the area for the hidden field is totally empty.
(This is in IE 11)

EDIT: Fixed But example code of the before an after, looking for an explanation on why this fixed it.

Working version

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <script src="webcam.min.js"></script>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
        <div id="CameraDivtest"></div>
             <input type="button" id="start" value="startCamera" onclick="videoCall('test')" />
        <input type="button" value="take picture" id="picButtonKey" />



    </div>
    </form>
     <script>
         var c;
         var v;
         var con;
         function videoCall(type) {


             Webcam.set({
                 width: 600,
                 height: 420
             });
             Webcam.attach('#CameraDiv' + type);

             function goingGrey() {
                 Webcam.snap(function (data_uri, canvas, context) {
                     var pngUrl = data_uri
                     document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>").value = type + pngUrl;
                     document.forms[0].submit();


                });

            }


            document.getElementById("picButtonKey").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                goingGrey();


            });


        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Broken version

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <script src="webcam.min.js"></script>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
        <div id="CameraDivtest"></div>
             <input type="button" id="start" value="startCamera" onclick="videoCall('test')" />
        <input type="button" value="take picture" id="picButtonKey" />



    </div>
    </form>
     <script>
         var c;
         var v;
         var con;
         function videoCall(type) {


             Webcam.set({
                 width: 600,
                 height: 420
             });
             Webcam.attach('#CameraDiv' + type);

             function goingGrey() {
                 Webcam.snap(function (data_uri, canvas, context) {
                     var pngUrl = data_uri
                     document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>").value = type + pngUrl;



                });

            }


            document.getElementById("picButtonKey").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                goingGrey();
    document.forms[0].submit();


            });


        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you get the ID like `<%=  HiddenField1.ClientID %>`, and try again?

Comment: The value is being successfully set in the DOM and i know ive got the correct Client ID, I have already tried this and it did not work.

Comment: Could you create a stand alone aspx *(with minimum amount of code)* and upload the code so that we can replicate the issue?

Comment: Done, but i have no idea why what i did fixed it.

Comment: @Win Any idea why this fixed it?